# REGEXP_REPLACE not working as expected in Databricks job to remove specific pattern

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks, regexp-replace

I am facing an issue while populating a consumption view in Databricks. I'm using the following query to remove a specific pattern (number in parentheses) from a given column:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  column_name,
  '\\s\\(\\d+\\)\$',
  ''
) AS final_column
```

When I run this code manually in Databricks, it works as expected and removes the pattern. However, when I execute the same code as part of a Databricks job to populate the consumption view, the pattern isn't getting removed. I'm not sure why this is happening.

**It's worth noting that the manually testing cluster uses Spark 3.1.2, whereas the Databricks job that populates the view uses Spark 3.0.1.**

Here's an example to better illustrate the problem:

Input data:

```
column_name
--------------
Test Data (1)
Another Test (2)
```

Expected output:

```
final_column
--------------
Test Data
Another Test
```

Why is the REGEXP_REPLACE not working when I run it as part of a Databricks job to populate the consumption view, while it works perfectly when executed manually in Databricks? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect it's something like the interface when you run manually lets you get sloppy with backslashes, where the job doesn't.  I noticed only one backslash in front of the end-of-string character.  Is that even needed?  Try adding one there to match the other characters? Remove the doubled-up ones to singles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of triple \ instead of double \ resolved the issue. Also, the last \ before $ character is not required.

This is the updated expression:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  column_name,
  '\\\s\\\(\\\d+\\\)$',
  ''
) AS final_column
```